# What does an expert recommend: Angular Authentication within $routeProvider/resolve or $routeChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, authentication

While digging into the options doing Authentication/Authorization within Angular I found 2 possibilities in general:

The first and maybe mainly used option is to create a `resolve` function within the `angular.config`/`$routeProvider.when(...)` functions.
E.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/811782/AngularJS-Security-Authorization-on-Angular-Routes

The second possibility is to check the user rights within `angular.run`/ `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', ...)`.
E.g http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

I found many examples for both, but not an explanation why I should use the first or the second option. My idea was, `resolve` could be cancel the route request before `$routeChangeStart` is invoked. Regardless this, with resolve I have to implement the check for every route (except e.g. with UI-Router). The `$routeChangeStart` approach to me seems more like a middleware approach and therefore the better choice.

Somebody could me tell other/more reasons for this or that?